# is rydberg constant and rydberg unit are same?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, hydrogen, units

i want to ask a question that.is rydberg constant and rydberg unit are same. UNIT OF RYDBERG CONSTANT IS m^-1, right? Then what is rydberg unit.

Comment: Read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant).